# Twitter API curl request to oauth/request_token returns null - php 5.6

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

So I have this very simple app that must post to it's own profile, and that's basically it.

As far as I know right now, I need to go through 3-legged oauth to get my token, which, from what I've read, lasts basically forever, which is good.

anyway, I'm doing a little experiment, in which I curl my way to the oauth token I need to post.

Here's the code:

```
<?php


/*
The Request I wanna make, as described basically here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token
Part of this flow: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth

curl -XPOST
  --url 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
  --header 'OAuth
  oauth_nonce="K7ny27JTpKVsTgdyLdDfmQQWVLERj2zAK5BslRsqyw",

  oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="1300228849",
  oauth_consumer_key="OqEqJeafRSF11jBMStrZz",
  oauth_signature="Pc%2BMLdv028fxCErFyi8KXFM%2BddU%3D",
  oauth_version="1.0"'
*/

$request_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

$consumer_secret = '[Consumer secret from my apps details > keys & tokens]';
$token_secret = '[token secret I got from my apps details > keys & tokens]';

$signature_key = "$consumer_secret&$token_secret";


$time = time();
$nonce = hash('md5', $time);
$callback = urlencode('http://localhost:8000/admin/twitter.callback.php');
$signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
$consumer_key = '[key from my apps detials > keys & tokens]';
$oauth_version = '1.0';

$payload = "oauth_nonce=$nonce&oauth_callback=$callback&oauth_signature_method=$signature_method&oauth_timestamp=$time&oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key&oauth_version=1.0";

$to_be_signed = "POST&" . urlencode($request_url) . "&" . urlencode($payload);

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $to_be_signed, $signature_key, true));



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,       true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: " . "OAuth
oauth_nonce=\"$nonce\",

oauth_callback=\"$callback\",
oauth_signature_method=\"$signature_method\",
oauth_timestamp=\"$time\",
oauth_consumer_key=\"$consumer_key\",
oauth_signature=\"$signature\",
oauth_version=\"$oauth_version\""));

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);


curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
// prints out NULL.
```

Something is wrong here, I just don't know what.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Changing my headers to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("OAuth
oauth_nonce=\"$nonce\",

oauth_callback=\"$callback\",
oauth_signature_method=\"$signature_method\",
oauth_timestamp=\"$time\",
oauth_consumer_key=\"$consumer_key\",
oauth_version=\"$oauth_version\",
oauth_signature=\"$signature\""));
```

will result in the following output:

```
array(1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["code"]=>
      int(215)
      ["message"]=>
      string(24) "Bad Authentication data."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting the oauth variables alphabetically?

Comment: That is actually super interesting to hear. I was doing a different approach, that yielded no results, either, namely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128014/php-twitter-api-chunked-upload-problem-segments-do-not-add-up-to-provided-total

Comment: I am stuck there too (please help me out if you spot anything). but failing that, I might go back to THIS approach.

Comment: @AndyPiper just tried it. to no avail.

Comment: I gutted my twitter library. remade the entire thing.... it works(?) I just 1. dont know how I did it (but I'll paste a non-spaghetti version tomorrow) 2. I'm stuck at the exact same error I had with the library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128014/php-twitter-api-chunked-upload-problem-segments-do-not-add-up-to-provided-total