# PHP Twitter API chunked upload problem: Segments do not add up to provided total file size

Tags: php, api, twitter

so I am integrating the Twitter API into an app, and I need it to be able to post images, videos, and animated gifs.

I am using php5.6 and the J7mbo/twitter-api-php package.

My code thus far is as follows:

```
     $file = fopen(realpath('../path/' . $row['path']), 'rb');
      $size = fstat($file)['size'];
      $mime_type = mime_content_type($row['path']);

      var_dump($size);
      var_dump($mime_type);


      $upload_url = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json';
      $requestMethod = 'POST';

  $postfields = array(
          "command" => "INIT",
          'media_type' => $mime_type,
        //  'media_category' => 'tweet_video',
          'total_bytes' => $size
      );

      $initResult = json_decode($twitter->buildOauth($upload_url, $requestMethod)
        ->setPostfields($postfields)
        ->performRequest());


      $mediaId = $initResult->media_id_string;

      $segmentId = 0;

      while (!feof($file)) {
        $chunk = fread($file, 100000);

          echo strlen($chunk);


          $postfields = array(
              "command" => "APPEND",
              "media_id" => $mediaId,
              "segment_index" => $segmentId,

              "media" => $chunk
          );

          //var_dump($chunk);

          $appendResult = $twitter->buildOauth($upload_url, $requestMethod)
            ->setPostfields($postfields)
            ->performRequest();

          echo('chunk: '. $segmentId);

          var_dump($appendResult);

          $segmentId++;
      }

      echo ('done uploading');

      fclose($file);

      $postfields = array(
          "command" => "FINALIZE",
          "media_id" => $mediaId
      );

      $finResult = $twitter->buildOauth($upload_url, $requestMethod)
        ->setPostfields($postfields)
        ->performRequest();

      var_dump($finResult);
```

No matter how big or small my chunks, the result of the FINALIZE request is always:

```
{"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"Segments do not add up to provided total file size."}"
```

What's most frustrating is the fact that in my tests, $size is 273872 and no matter how I split my chunks, their total length is ALWAYS, 100% guaranteed to be 273872.

What is even going on here? how do I even go about debugging this?

the INIT works. 
The append returns "" but according to twitter's documentation (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append) that is exactly correct. I do not know how to extract the response status, though, so I'm far from certain.

PS: I havent used any of the social network apis in a long time I don't exactly know what could be relevant to tell you, please, request anything you'd like me to add to this post.

EDIT: I have remade this with curl. I have the exact same result. I thought "maybe it's processing or whatever", so I did 2 tests:

- Ask for the status (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/get-media-upload-status) of the upload. I consistently get the following result

```
     {
            ["errors"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["message"]=>
                    string(31) "Sorry, that page does not exist"
                    ["code"]=>
                    int(34)
                  }
                }
         }
```

Have no idea if I'll get it with this library. Will try tomorrow.

- I've tried sleeping for 20 seconds... same result. It's probably something else.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

it's to years later but...

you should base64 encode your chunk

```
"media" => base64_encode($chunk)
```